# How to list out directories in command line using python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to list out all sub-directories in a directory like a dropdown in command line using python! I got this idea from [Light Table](http://lighttable.com/) editor. I've already looked at [argparse](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-master-python-command-line-arguments-5d5ad4bcf985) library in python. Light Table editors' image on change theme with options in a dropdown. [image: updating theme using existing options like a dropdown]

Comment: You want to have a drop-down in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, the drop-down should populate existing sub-directories with search like mentioned in the image! Just now visited curses in python but no hope!

Comment: I won't say it's impossible, but it is going to be very complicated to implement. Basically a drop-down is the opposite of terminal.

Comment: `argparse` is just a tool for parsing commandline arguments, which it finds in the `sys.argv`.  It doesn't display anything, nor is it interactjve.

Comment: I agree! I mentioned that because it has an option to define choices in choosing arguments.  $ python employee.py Alex Manager --country Japan    
usage: employee.py [-h] [--address ADDRESS]
                   [--country {Singapore,United States,Malaysia}]
                   [--isFullTime ISFULLTIME]
                   name title
employee.py: error: argument --country: invalid choice: 'Japan' (choose from 'Singapore', 'United States', 'Malaysia') this will give choice to the user same as like I need to show in drop-down with search options in command-line.